# C# WCF Service not picking up properties from ajax post

Tags: c#, ajax, wcf

I have a WCF to save some data to my db.  In Dev Tools I can see the request payload as below:

```
{"OrderId":123456,"Year":"2017","CustomerId":999999,"LicencePlates":[{"licenceNumber":"222222222222222"}]}
```

My WCF service interface is as below:

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/SaveLicenceData", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
    void SaveLicenceData(int OrderId, int Year, string CustomerId, LicencePlate[] LicencePlates);
```

The licence plate class is:

```
public class LicencePlate
{
    [DataMember]
    public string LicenceNumber { get; set; }
}
```

With a breakpoint set, I can see the OrderId getting passed, the Year getting passed and the CustomerId getting passed.  However LicenceNumber I keep getting null passed.

I tried making the overall class `[Serializable]` but the breakpoint isn't even getting hit when I add this.  I also tried changing the annotation too  `[DataMember(Name = "licenceNumber")]`  but still getting null and then changed the annotation to   `[JsonProperty]` and still getting null.

Is there something stupid I have missed here?

Comment: does the wsdl match your class?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a case mismatch. In your payload you have

```
"licenceNumber":"222222222222222"
```

It should be

```
"LicenceNumber":"222222222222222"
```